# VB mysql date search is not working

Tags: mysql, vb6

Hello I am using VB6 and mysql and I am facing a problem in searching through dates its not fetching records

Here is my code

```
Dim GetDateNow As Date
Dim GetDateTen As String
Dim SetDateTen As Date
GetDateNow = Format$(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd")
GetDateTen = Now - 15
SetDateTen = Format$(GetDateTen, "yyyy-mm-dd")

Dim rs As New Recordset
SQL = "SELECT * FROM CreditPayLog WHERE payment_user='" & Label5.Caption & "' AND payment_date BETWEEN '" & Format(SetDateTen, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "' AND '" & Format(GetDateNow, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "'"
```

Also i have used **debug.print** function to see the query all looks good but its not fetching data here is the query

```
SELECT * FROM CreditPayLog WHERE payment_user='1222150322' AND payment_date BETWEEN '2016-04-06' AND '2016-04-21'
```

payment_date is **DATETIME** column in mysql

Comment: VB.NET IsNot VB6.  Please do not use inappropriate tags.

Comment: Apologize for my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Your sql is creating a text/string value for date... you need to cast as a date. Not sure how in mySQL but in MSSql you would use `Convert(datetime, 'yourDateAsString', 103)`

Comment: It is the str_to_date() function.